# Add 10px to left and right of page that's centered

Tags: html, css

My page is set at 100% width, so that my navigation bar goes across the entire screen. However, the page contents as well as the links in the nav bar are only 1000px wide and centered.

How can I add 10px on each side of the 1000px page so that when viewed in an iPhone, the text is not all the way to the edge of the screen?

ie.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: #000;
}

.nav-bar-links {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

page {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `padding` property like this:

```
.page {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
page {
    ...
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* keeps it at 1000px wide *with* padding */
}
```

It's not clear whether you'd actually like the space outside the page element. In that case, use padding on the body.

Side note: Did you mean `.page`?